# Postgres copy data with \xYY as plain string instead of interpreting as encoded string

Tags: postgresql, import, bulkcopy, encoding

I have a log file full of URLs, generated by [Bro](http://www.bro.org/) IDS.

When Bro logs a URL with non-ascii characters in it, it inserts \xYY where YY is the hexadecimal character code. Also, some URLs contain "\x".

Is there a setting or flag I can use with the `COPY` or `\copy` command to stop postgres from trying to interpret these string sequences and just put them in the text field as is?

Comment: Please make it a habit to supply what you have tried (even if it seems trivial), your PostgreSQL version and relevant configuration data (like database encoding in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash `\` is the default **escape character** in the (default) text format of `COPY`. The format you describe is recognized as ([quoting the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html#AEN66623))

> backslash sequences are recognized by `COPY FROM`
>   ...
>   \xdigits | Backslash x followed by one or two hex digits specifies the character with that numeric code

.. which seems to be just as intended.
To avoid this effect you could use the [CSV format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html#AEN66706) instead, where the backslash has no special meaning:

```
COPY tbl FROM '/path/to/file/log.sql' (FORMAT csv);
```

Be sure to read the manual to learn about additional differences.

Alternatively you could replace every `\` with `\\` in your file with a `sed` script or something.

If the above doesn't solve your problem, please supply:

- PostgreSQL version
- Database encoding
- Demo data
- Definition of the table you `COPY` to
- The exact `COPY` invocation you used

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just had to set the delimiter to \t a la:
`COPY to_table (col1,col2,col3) FROM '/path/to/file' with (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\t');`